# Как на Nginx сделать проксирование интернет потока радио с использованием https?

Tags: nginx, проксирование

Нужно сделать проксирование потока интернет радио через Nginx. Чтобы поток выдавался по https.

**Какие настройки нужно внести?**

Конфиг Nginx на сервере:

```
    server {
    server_name radio.radio.ru www.radio.radio.ru;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/radio.radio.ru/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/radio.radio.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/radio.radio.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    set $root_path /var/www/radio/data/www/radio.ru/radio;
    root $root_path;
    listen IP:80;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
}
server {
    server_name radio.radio.ru www.radio.radio.ru;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/radio/radio.radio.ru_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/radio/radio.radio.ru_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/radio.radio.ru/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/radio.radio.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/radio.radio.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/radio/data/www/radio.ru/radio;
    root $root_path;
    listen 91.215.169.139:443 ssl;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно купить ssl-cертификат или сгенерировать его с помощью letsencrypt и настроить сервер согласно инструкциям http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html